# Recompile a kernel including a firmware

Tags: linux-kernel, compiling, firmware, touch-screen, tablet

How can i recompile the kernel? I' m trying this guide https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel.

I' m using lubuntu 18.04 on a tablet, i want a custom kernel to enable the touchcreen.

Folowing this section took from https://github.com/onitake/gsl-firmware#silead_tsi made a custom `silead_dmi.c` (that is located in `drivers/platform/x86/silead_dmi.c`) and that refers to the `silead_ts.fw` firmware that i found here https://github.com/onitake/gsl-firmware/tree/master/firmware/trekstor/surftab7new (FYI Mediacom W700 is equivalent at SurfTab wintron 7.0 ST70416-6).

I used `apt-get source linux-headers-$(uname -r)` and got the `linux-4.15` folder of 800 MB. That has the path `drivers/platform/x86/silead_dmi.c` in which i made the `drivers/platform/x86/silead_dmi.c` file.

Following the guide i used `apt-get source linux-image-$(uname -r)` and got the `linux-signed-4.15.0` folder of 118 kB.
Now using `fakeroot debian/rules editconfigs` i get an error:

```
dh editconfigs
dh: Unknown sequence editconfigs (choose from: binary binary-arch binary-indep build build-arch build-indep clean install install-arch install-indep)
debian/rules:35: recipe for target 'editconfigs' failed
make: *** [editconfigs] Error 2
```

How can i fix this error and recompile the kernel?
And the folder obtained from `apt-get source linux-headers-$(uname -r)` which has the path `drivers/platform/x86/silead_dmi.c`?
And the firmware?

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1067640/enable-the-touchscreen-of-a-mediacom-winpad-w700 
If someone want more info can check there.

Comment: Fill a [bugreport](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs), or use the more conventional `make menuconfig` and `make deb-pkg`.

Comment: Of you are modifying sources, you are on your own, please do not fill frivolous bug reports

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro if i  fill  a request for a new software? Include tablet touchscrenn support. So the developers can do it. Using `make deb-pkg` i can transform the firmware into a installable package?

Comment: @IporSircer how can i use `make menuconfig` and make `deb-pkg`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `silead_ts.fw` is for this deprecated project https://github.com/onitake/gslx680-acpi. 
You should use at least the https://github.com/onitake/gsl-firmware/blob/master/firmware/trekstor/surftab7new/firmware.fw, fimrware only extracted and not modified for the old project.

But you must use this https://github.com/onitake/gsl-firmware/blob/master/firmware/linux/silead/gsl1686-surftab-wintron70-st70416-6.fw ,put the file in `/lib/firmware/silead`(create the folder `silead`). Also made a copy with the name `mssl1680.fw` (backup firmware).

Now follow this guide for recompile the kernel https://debian-handbook.info/browse/squeeze/sect.kernel-compilation.html.
Use `apt-cache search ^linux-source` to find the source for the kernel (as the guide explains).

In the `silead_dmi.c` file add:

```
static const struct property_entry mediacom_w700_props[] = {
    PROPERTY_ENTRY_U32("touchscreen-size-x", 884),
    PROPERTY_ENTRY_U32("touchscreen-size-y", 632),
    PROPERTY_ENTRY_STRING("firmware-name",
                  "gsl1686-surftab-wintron70-st70416-6.fw"),
    PROPERTY_ENTRY_U32("silead,max-fingers", 10),
    PROPERTY_ENTRY_BOOL("silead,home-button"),
    { }
};
```

And most important in the DMI_MATCH add:

```
 {
        /* Mediacom WinPad 7.0 W700 */
        .driver_data = (void *)&surftab_wintron70_st70416_6_data,
        .matches = {
            DMI_MATCH(DMI_SYS_VENDOR, "MEDIACOM"),
                DMI_MATCH(DMI_PRODUCT_NAME, "WinPad 7 W10 - WPW700"),
        },
    },
```

Comment: wow! +1 for answering your own question. I have a similar problem with another Trektor: YOURBOOKC11b. I wish the kernel would support this by default... are you still running the same kernel-version? or do you recompile every now and then with new kernel-releases?

Comment: If I still had the tablet I think I would recompile the kernel every now and then. But it is broken.